# How can I make Lilypond start lyrics on the very first note?

Tags: notation, lilypond, lyrics

With Lilypond, I'm trying to notate a song with lyrics - this song has lyrics sung from the very first note of the piece.  But Lilypond always shifts the words over one note each (see image).  I can't seem to make Lilypond align the lyrics properly with the notes.... I'm stumped!!

Here's my Lilypond code:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "english.ly"

\header
{
  title = "Eleanor Rigby"
  composer = "John Lennon / Paul McCartney"
  tagline = ##f
}

\score
{
  \new StaffGroup
  <<
    \new Staff = "vocal-melody"
    {
      \new Voice = "vocal"
      {
        \set Staff.autoBeaming = ##f
        \clef treble
        \numericTimeSignature
        \time 4/4
        \tempo 4 = #128
        \key e \minor
        \relative c'
        {
          e2~ e8 fs g a~
          a8 g4 fs e4 b16[( a])
          g2 r2
        }
      }
    }

    \new Lyrics
    {
      \override LyricHyphen.minimum-distance = #1.0
      \lyricsto "vocal"
      {
        Ahh, look at all the lone - ly peo - ple.
      }
    }

    \new GrandStaff
    {
      <<
        \new Staff = "up"
        {
          \clef treble
          \numericTimeSignature
          \time 4/4
          \key e \minor
          \relative c'
          {
            R1*3
          }
        }

        \new Staff = "down"
        {
          \clef bass
          \numericTimeSignature
          \time 4/4
          \key e \minor
          \relative c,
          {
            R1*3
          }
        }
      >>
    }
  >>

  \layout
  {
  }
}
```

[image]

How might I be able to properly align the lyrics to the music?

Comment: To digress: please consider reinstating auto-beaming. As a singer, I _hate_ the style of notation where beams are used to indicate syllables and not rhythm; it's much harder to read a mass of individual notes when they're not properly beamed, and you can (and arguably should) use slurs to indicate melisma.

Comment: Also: you have a related minor problem with the lyric spacing, as it's assigned a bare ‘-’ to a note. The solution is to use `--` instead of `-` when writing the lyrics; Lilypond then knows it's to join two syllables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't want to start off your `Lyrics` context with separate music events, so put your settings in a context modification instead of the music.

To wit:

```
\new Lyrics \with { \override LyricHyphen.minimum-distance = #1.0 }
\lyricsto ...
```